# How to verify data in a linear fit for a sensor? Experimental vs Expected data

Tags: p-value, experiment-design, expected-value, linear

I am trying to characterize a sensor; in which I am trying to obtain the time constant as a function of the pressure applied to the sensor. I fitted a linear trend line into this data. However, I was told that a way to verify if these tau values that I am obtaining are significant is to perform a P-test. I have been reading around and want to see if I understood how to perform this correctly or if it is even the correct approach to verify these values.

It is to my understanding that to perform the P-test I would obtain the tau values from the fitted line and compare them to the ones that I obtained in the experiment. This should give me back a P-value in which I would determine if the experimental data is statistically significant or not.

Any clarification or advice is appreciated since I am not familiar with statistics. Thank you.

[image]